# Create dynamic HTML table

Tags: html, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

How to create a dynamic table HTML using blade `foreach` loop like this one:

[image]

which merge rows that are same like name, father name and type.

I've created my table but it brings the first record complete and the reset incomplete without merging the rows of like this:

[image]

My view

```
        <tbody>
        @php
            $rowid = 0;
            $rowspan = 0;
        @endphp
        @foreach($result as $key => $data)
            @php
                $rowid += 1
            @endphp
            <tr>
                @if ($key == 0 || $rowspan == $rowid)
                    @php
                        $rowid = 0;
                        $rowspan = $data->driver_name;
                    @endphp
            <td id="" rowspan="{{$result->count()}}"></td>
            <td id="" rowspan="{{$result->count()}}">{{$data->driver_name}}</td>
            <td id="" rowspan="{{$result->count()}}">{{$data->father_name}}</td>
            <td id="" rowspan="{{$result->count()}}">{{$data->vehicle_type}}</td>
            <td id="" rowspan="{{$result->count()}}">{{$data->plate_no}}</td>
            <td id="" rowspan="{{$result->count()}}">{{$data->serial_number}}</td>
            <td id="" rowspan="{{$result->count()}}">{{$data->description}}</td>
            <td id="" rowspan="{{$result->count()}}">{{$data->created_at}}</td>
            <td id="" rowspan="{{$result->count()}}">{{$data->order_number}}</td>
            <td id="" rowspan="{{$result->count()}}">{{$data->export_number}}</td>
                @endif
            <td id="">{{$data->buy_parts}}</td>
            <td id="">{{$data->quantity}}</td>
            <td id="">{{$data->per_item_price}}</td>
            <td id="">{{$data->total_price}}</td>
                    @if ($key == 0 || $rowspan == $rowid)
                        @php
                            $rowid = 0;
                            $rowspan = $data->driver_name;
                        @endphp
            <td id="" rowspan="{{$result->count()}}">{{$data->export_date}}</td>
            <td id="" rowspan="{{$result->count()}}">{{$data->remarks}}</td>
                        @endif
        </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
```

My Controller:

```
    public function repair_parts()
    {
        $result=DB::table('parts_orders as a')
            ->select('b.emp_id','c.name as driver_name','c.father_name','d.vehicle_type','d.plate_no','b.id as serial_number'
                ,'b.description','b.created_at','a.order_number','a.export_number','a.buy_parts','a.per_item_price','a.quantity'
                ,'a.total_price','a.export_date','a.remarks')
            ->join('repair_cars as b','a.repair_id','=','b.id','left')
            ->join('drivers as c','b.emp_id','=','c.emp_id','left')
            ->join('vehicles as d','b.vechcal_id','=','d.plate_no','left')
            ->join('locations as e','b.location_id','=','e.id','left')
            ->get();
        return view('Reports/repair_parts_report',compact('result'));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way.

Data array

```
@php
        $rows = [

            [
                'remarks'   => 'remark',
                'date'  => '2019-07-09',
                'total' => [100,200,300],
                'quantity'  => [100,200,300],
                'partname'  => ['a','b','c'],
                'number'    => '123412',
                'ordernumber'   => 'RNX123',
                'orderdate' => '2019-07-09',
                'desc'  => 'some descriptioin',
                'saledate'  => '2019-07-09',
                'datenumber'    => '99884',
                'type'  => 'test',
                'father'    => 'father',
                'name'      =>  'name',
            ],
            [
                'remarks'   => 'remark',
                'date'  => '2019-07-09',
                'total' => [100,200,300],
                'quantity'  => [100,200,300],
                'partname'  => ['a','b','c'],
                'number'    => '123412',
                'ordernumber'   => 'RNX123',
                'orderdate' => '2019-07-09',
                'desc'  => 'some descriptioin',
                'saledate'  => '2019-07-09',
                'datenumber'    => '99884',
                'type'  => 'test',
                'father'    => 'father',
                'name'      =>  'name',
            ],
        ]
    @endphp
```

blade part.

```
<table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>Remarks</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Part Name</th>
                    <th>Number</th>
                    <th>Order Number</th>
                    <th>Order Date</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Sale Date</th>
                    <th>Date Number</th>
                    <th>Type</th>
                    <th>
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr><th colspan="2"> Urdu</th></tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Father</th>
                                <th>Name</th>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </th>
                    <th>#</th>
                </tr>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($rows as $key => $row)
                <tr>
                    <td> {{$row['remarks']}}</td>
                    <td> {{$row['date']}}</td>
                    <td>
                         @foreach($row['total'] as $total)
                        <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $total}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        @endforeach 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         @foreach($row['quantity'] as $quantity)
                        <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $quantity}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        @endforeach 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                         @foreach($row['partname'] as $partname)
                        <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $partname}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        @endforeach 
                    </td>
                    <td> {{$row['number']}}</td>
                    <td> {{$row['ordernumber']}}</td>
                    <td> {{$row['orderdate']}}</td>
                    <td> {{$row['desc']}}</td>
                    <td> {{$row['datenumber']}}</td>
                    <td> {{$row['type']}}</td>
                    <td> {{$row['father']}}</td>
                    <td> {{$row['name']}}</td>
                    <td> {{ $key+1}}</td>

                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

OutPut.

[image: Above code description]

I hope you will get some idea from this.

Comment: Thanks for your replay but it say's "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" after adding ```@foreach($row['quantity'] as $quantity)
                        <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $quantity}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                        @endforeach ```

Comment: It is because you have object not array, you can access it like `$row->quantity`.